# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Tags: javascript

У меня проблема uncaught TypeError, но я уже изучил все вопросы насчет этого случая, все не то. До меня сайт создавал другой программист, и короче мой код не работает с его кодом, я попробовал на чистом файле все это запустить, все работает, но с его кодом нет. Из-за этого я открыл репозиторий на github, пожалуйста, помогите решить проблему. Если отдельно запустить скрипт, все работает, если в перемешку, то ошибка

[Вот сама ссылка на репозиторий](https://github.com/jek701/audio.git)

Comment: интересно на что вы надеялись, когда писали этот "вопрос"

Comment: Не ругайте пожалуйста((, я учусь только. Спасибо Азиз ака, помогли! Получилось

Comment: Не вопрос пользуйтесь аккуратнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перенесите в конец body.

```
<script src="js/1-min.js?v=1"></script>
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>
        (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
                new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
                'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
                })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-PWQ6PN4');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Вы на право и на лево используете document когда на момент запуска скрипта DOM может быть и не готова